# Direct Sums with $\{0\}$: is this a correct proof?

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

Suppose $U \oplus W = V$. Prove that $U \oplus W \oplus \{0\} = V$.

This is a proof that I thought of when asking a question on here a bit earlier:

Let $U$ and $W$ be subspaces of $V$. 
If $U \oplus W = V$, then $U + W = V$, and the only combination $u + w$ where $u \in U$ and $w \in W$ that yields the $0$ vector is $v = w = 0$. Consider an additional element $z \in \{0\}$. In order for the condition, $0 = 0 + 0 + z$ to be satisfied, it must be that $ z = 0$. Since it is true that for any $z \neq 0, z \not\in \{0\}$, we can conclude that $U \oplus W \oplus \{0\} = V$.

Is this valid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's almost fine, except I think you've got the direct sum condition slightly mis-worded. You want to assume that $u + w + z = 0$ with $u \in U$, $w \in W$ and $z \in \{0\}$. This condition implies that $u + w = 0$, so that $u = w = 0$.

You've assumed that $u = w = 0$ in order to show that $z = 0$, which is backwards.

Comment: But if V is already defined as $U \oplus W$, couldn't we conclude that the only combination for $0 \in u + w$ where $u \in U$ and $w \in W$ is $u = w = 0$?

Comment: Yes, that's right. I just thought your wording was backwards, since you effectively assume what you're trying to prove.

Comment: This question led from another I had asked earlier about direct sums and my false assumption that if there is a direct sum of subspaces $U_1 \oplus \cdots \oplus Un$, then $U_1 \not\subset \cdots \not\subset U_n$ and $U_1 \not\supset \cdots \not\supset U_n$ for $u_1 \in U_1,\ldots, u_n \in U_n$. However, this did not rule out the case that there might be a $U_j \in \{0\}$. So I just thought of a random case where the subspace $\{0\}$ was added to to an arbitrary vector space expressed as a direct sum. It was more of a lame exercise that I made up more than anything else. :D